# Odoo SSO With Azure AD

Tags: azure-active-directory, odoo

We installed odoo 12 and try to connect with azure AD. Users are authenticated successfully via Azure AD OAuth but it showing error AADSTS50011: The reply url specified in the request does not match the reply urls configured for the application.

Answer (score 0):

This error usually occurs when the redirect_uri in the authorization request mismatch the redirect url configured in Azure portal.

You can find the redirect_uri in the authentication url:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/authorize? client_id=6731de76-14a6-49ae-97bc-6eba6914391e &response_type=code &redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A12345 &response_mode=query &resource=https%3A%2F%2Fservice.contoso.com%2F &state=12345
```

Copy the value of redirect_uri and paste it to Azure portal(Authentication->redirect URI).

Comment: Hi,

We are facing Redirect URI issue when we login Via Azure AD.  We installed odoo 12 and try to connect with azure AD. Users are authenticated successfully via Azure AD OAuth but it showing error AADSTS50011: The reply url specified in the request does not match the reply urls configured for the application.  

When we saw the URL it showing http://odoo.example.com not https. Can anyone helpus to set correct redirect URI with https.

Comment: @Raghul How did you config the ad auth? can you find the config for redirect url?

Answer (score 0):

To set up the connection, you need to create a new application in the [Azure Portal](https://portal.azure.com/), add the appropriate API permissions, assign users and groups, and generate the Client ID and Client Secret.

Under the Redirect URL section, select Web as the platform, and then input

```
https://<odoo base url>/microsoft_outlook/confirm
```

API permissions
Odoo will need specific API permissions to be able to read (IMAP) and send (SMTP) emails in the Microsoft 365 setup. First, click the API permissions link, located in the left menu bar. Next, click on the (+) Add a Permission button and select Microsoft Graph under Commonly Used Microsoft APIs. After, select the Delegated Permissions option.

In the search bar, search for the following Deregulated permissions and click Add permissions for each one:

SMTP.Send

IMAP.AccessAsUser.All

[image: API Permission]

[This link has described step by step:](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/16.0/administration/maintain/azure_oauth.html)